# How to set a color for a string inside hint?

Tags: java, android

I have a string variable 'user' derived from an edittext. I use this variable in a 
hint with some text. It works well but I need the color of that varibale 'user' 
inside the hint to be displayed in red. I tried previous answers but they are not helpful as the colour remains unchanged.

```
final EditText modifyTxt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
String user = modifyTxt1.getText().toString().trim();

newTxt.setHint("You have just now created a title : " +user+"");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this

1) from java code

```
newTxt.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

OR

2) from layout xml

```
android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 2):

in your xml file where you want to add hint 
add the following line

```
 android:textColorHint=""
```

and fill it with the colour you want to add

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way

```
String hintText="You have just now created a title : <font color='red'>" +user+"</font>";
```

Use the  `Html.fromHtml` method to convert this back into a styled character
sequence.

```
newTxt.setHint(Html.fromHtml(hintText ));
```

Note that `Html.fromHtml()` parses your text as html.

Answer (score 1):

```
newTxt.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'>Hello</font> "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String myText = "You have just now created a title : ";
    String user = "abc";
    Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(user);        
    String total = myText+user;
    int length = total.length();
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 36, length-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    newTxt.setText(textViewProgressStatus.toString());
```